# Using this with generator function in classes

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux-saga, es6-class

I seem to be unable to use the `this` reference in a class with sagas / generator functions

```
export default class Foo {

  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name
  }

  *sayHello() {
    yield put('@@actions/say Hello', this.name)
  }  
}

// In a Saga
const foo = new Foo('World')
yield call(foo.sayHello) // Crashes as `this` becomes undefined
```

I found a small hack which is to pass the class itself as an argument so it could read the class variables, but it feels too hackish (and not thread safe but in my case it's not rly important)

```
// Use special argument which is the class itself
*sayHello(self) {
  yield put({type: '@@actions/SAY_HELLO', name: self.name})
}  

call(foo.sayHello, foo) // Works
```

Comment: `call(foo.sayHello.bind(foo))` or `call(() => foo.sayHello())`

Comment: Could potentially be a bug in the transpiler, might be worth having a look at the transpiled code.

Comment: @DuncanThacker No, it's the correct behaviour in native ES6 as well

Comment: This has nothing to do with generators per se, you're just passing a *method* as a *callback* to that `call` function

Comment: Thanks @Bergi that explains a few things.